# AngularJS / Karma unit testing with real XHR data / passThrough()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, karma-runner

I would like to use real $http data for my unit test using passThrough().

Here's what I have so far:

```
var should = chai.should();
beforeEach(module('myApp', 'ngMockE2E'));
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _$http_) {
  $scope = _$rootScope_;
  $http = _$http_;
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
}));

it.only('blah', function(done) {
 $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/data').passThrough();

  $scope.$apply(function() {
  $http.get('/api/data').success(function(data) {
   data.should.eql({"foo": "bar"});
    done();
  });
});

// Evidently not required with E2E
//$httpBackend.flush();

});
```

But this gives an error:

```
Unexpected request: GET /api/data
No more request expected
Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/data
No more request expected
```

If I remove the apply call it times out.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you would be running karma on a different port than the port where the services with real data are available. If you could re-route your requests to the server/port where the services with real data are running, such that it does not encounter [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), you will be able to make it work. In my project, I use [Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to [map urls](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-remote/) to get around CORS when using `passThrough()`.
You can also make your real data services CORS compatible to ease things up.

Comment: Thanks, man. Normally, I would wait to test this before accepting (or in my case, awarding the bounty), but your answer seems like it's exactly correct. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Also, I haven't heard of (though the name sounds familiar) Charles proxy.